# Tensorflow linear regression result does not match Numpy/SciKit-Learn

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, scikit-learn, linear-regression

I am working through the Tensorflow examples from Aurelien Geron's "Hands-On Machine Learning" book. However, I am unable to replicate the simple linear regression example in [this supporting notebook](https://github.com/ageron/handson-ml/issues). Why doesn't Tensorflow match the Numpy/SciKit-Learn result?

As far as I can tell, there is no optimization (we are using the normal equation, so it's just matrix computations), and the answers seem too different to be precision errors.

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from sklearn.datasets import fetch_california_housing

housing = fetch_california_housing()
m, n = housing.data.shape
housing_data_plus_bias = np.c_[np.ones((m, 1)), housing.data]

X = tf.constant(housing_data_plus_bias, dtype=tf.float32, name="X")
y = tf.constant(housing.target.reshape(-1, 1), dtype=tf.float32, name="y")
XT = tf.transpose(X)
theta = tf.matmul(tf.matmul(tf.matrix_inverse(tf.matmul(XT, X)), XT), y)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    theta_value = theta.eval()

theta_value
```

Answer:

```
array([[ -3.74651413e+01],
       [  4.35734153e-01],
       [  9.33829229e-03],
       [ -1.06622010e-01],
       [  6.44106984e-01],
       [ -4.25131839e-06],
       [ -3.77322501e-03],
       [ -4.26648885e-01],
       [ -4.40514028e-01]], dtype=float32)
```

**###### Compare with pure NumPy**

```
X = housing_data_plus_bias
y = housing.target.reshape(-1, 1)
theta_numpy = np.linalg.inv(X.T.dot(X)).dot(X.T).dot(y)

print(theta_numpy)
```

Answer:

```
[[ -3.69419202e+01]
 [  4.36693293e-01]
 [  9.43577803e-03]
 [ -1.07322041e-01]
 [  6.45065694e-01]
 [ -3.97638942e-06]
 [ -3.78654265e-03]
 [ -4.21314378e-01]
 [ -4.34513755e-01]]
```

**###### Compare with Scikit-Learn**

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
lin_reg = LinearRegression()
lin_reg.fit(housing.data, housing.target.reshape(-1, 1))

print(np.r_[lin_reg.intercept_.reshape(-1, 1), lin_reg.coef_.T])
```

Answer:

```
[[ -3.69419202e+01]
 [  4.36693293e-01]
 [  9.43577803e-03]
 [ -1.07322041e-01]
 [  6.45065694e-01]
 [ -3.97638942e-06]
 [ -3.78654265e-03]
 [ -4.21314378e-01]
 [ -4.34513755e-01]]
```

Update: My question sounded similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47725664/tensorflow-import-causing-numpy-calculation-errors), but following the recommendation did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just compare the results by `tensorflow` and `numpy`. Since you used `dtype=tf.float32` for `X` and `y`, I will use `np.float32` for the `numpy` example as follows:

```
X_numpy = housing_data_plus_bias.astype(np.float32)
y_numpy = housing.target.reshape(-1, 1).astype(np.float32)
```

Now let's try to compare the results by `tf.matmul(XT, X)` (`tensorflow`) and `X.T.dot(X)` (`numpy`):

```
with tf.Session() as sess:
    XTX_value = tf.matmul(XT, X).eval()
XTX_numpy = X_numpy.T.dot(X_numpy)

np.allclose(XTX_value, XTX_numpy, rtol=1e-06) # True
np.allclose(XTX_value, XTX_numpy, rtol=1e-07) # False
```

So this is the problem of `float`'s precision. If you change the precision to `tf.float64` and `np.float64`, you will have the same result for `theta`.

Comment: That did the trick. So it was the precision after all...*facepalm*. Thanks!